# C# Explicit operator and Object

Tags: c#, typeconverter, explicit-conversion

**QUESTION**

Please take a look to the code first.

Here is my custom class:

```
public class float2D
{
    public float X { get; private set; }
    public float Y { get; private set; }

    public float2D(float x, float y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public static explicit operator Point(float2D x)
    {
        return new Point((int)x.X, (int)x.Y);
    }

    ...
}
```

And here is the test code I wrote:

```
    private void TEST()
    {
        float2D V = new float2D(1, 1);
        Point P = Point.Empty;
        P = (Point)V; // Works
        P = (Point)(V as object); // Specified cast is not valid.
    }
```

As you can see it failed to convert the value when value type is not known. I believe this happens because it search in Object class for operand not in real type. How can I solve this problem?

I have a code where EVERYTHING is object and it must take care of these conversations.

Please tell me if you have any Idea.

---

**AVOIDING DYNAMIC**

Ok let change the sample in the way you can see what I exactly want to do and what is my situation.

Here is the class I have:

```
    class TEST
    {
        dynamic OBJECT;
        public void STORE<T>(ref T V)
        {
            this.OBJECT = V;
        }

        public T CONVERT<T>()
        {
            return (T)this.OBJECT;
        }
    }
```

And here is the test code:

```
        float2D V = new float2D(1, 1);
        TEST t = new TEST();
        t.STORE(ref V);
        Point P = t.CONVERT<Point>();
```

Is there way I can drop dynamic from above class and keep it working? I really want to avoid .Net4/4.5

Comment: See: [Representation and identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx)

Comment: Aside here; why are you casting X and Y to integers?

Comment: @daveL - I'd assume its because the [constructor for Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9b80s6c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes integers.

Comment: The `explicit` and `implicit` conversion operators are evaluated at _compile time_. That means that the types as you have them at compile time must be fully known to apply those operators. When you convert `V` to `object`, you've essentially lost the type information and the compiler cannot make the determination to use the conversion operator you defined on `float2D`. _However_ you can cheat using the `dynamic` keyword; this will cause the Dynamic Language Runtime to evaluate _at runtime_ if there is a conversion operator or not. Try casting to `object`, then to `dynamic`, then to `Point`.

Comment: That said, I don't really recommend using `dynamic` for that purpose unless you really need to; most likely you can solve it in other ways. Perhaps with a utility function that checks the type of the incoming object, casts it to its compile-time type (`float2D`) if it's compatible, then casts/converts it to a `Point` object.

Comment: Son, I suggest you perform a big refactor on this project. Get rid of all those untype `object` variables.

Comment: @Jamiec lol indeed it does. Time for lunch.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, Thanks for information. I already solved it with Dynamic. Yet I really want to avoid it as it is a .Net4 thing. Please see edit.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati: I've posted a couple options to work around this that should be compatible with .NET 2.0/3.5. Overall though, I think this points to some design issues with your application, though I suspect in this case it's a matter of legacy and not exactly viable to refactor it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by other answers, you can't do this because you're trying to apply *runtime* casting to *compile time* conversion operations.

If you want to avoid `dynamic` because you don't want to use .NET 4.0's DLR, you could use reflection to find the conversion operators yourself. Can't comment on performance for your particular application doing this however:

```
public static TOutgoing Convert<TOutgoing>(object obj)
{
    Type incomingType = obj.GetType();

    MethodInfo conversionOperator = null;
    foreach(var method in incomingType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        if (
            method.Name == "op_Explicit" && //explicit converter
            method.ReturnType == typeof(TOutgoing) && //returns your outgoing ("Point") type
            method.GetParameters().Length == 1 && //only has 1 input parameter
            method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == incomingType //parameter type matches your incoming ("float2D") type
            )
        {
            conversionOperator = method;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (conversionOperator != null)
        return (TOutgoing)conversionOperator.Invoke(null, new object[]{obj});

    throw new Exception("No conversion operator found");
}
```

Or for .NET 3.5 with LINQ:

```
public static TOutgoing Convert<TOutgoing>(object obj)
{
    Type incomingType = obj.GetType();

    var conversionOperator = incomingType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(m => m.Name == "op_Explicit")
        .Where(m => m.ReturnType == typeof(TOutgoing))
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1 && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == incomingType)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (conversionOperator != null)
        return (TOutgoing)conversionOperator.Invoke(null, new object[]{obj});

    throw new Exception("No conversion operator found");
}
```

Usage:

```
float2D V = new float2D(1, 1);
Point P = Point.Empty;
P = Convert<Point>(V); //passes
P = Convert<Point>((V as object)); //passes
```

You can add "op_Implicit" as well if you wish to convert via implicit operators.

---

Another option if you want to avoid reflection is to pre-register the conversion functions, some casting and type lookups to determine which conversion operator to use.

Just a caveat, the solution here has a couple issues (thread safety, assumption that conversion functions exist, registering colliding/duplicate conversion functions throws errors) so use at your own risk or use it as a guide to modify as it suits your needs.

Basic gist is to define a simple converter to wrap the conversion functions themselves:

```
public interface IConverter
{
    object Convert(object incomingObject);
}

public class Converter<TIncoming, TOutgoing> : IConverter
{
    private Func<TIncoming, TOutgoing> ConversionFunction;

    public Converter(Func<TIncoming, TOutgoing> conversionFunction)
    {
        this.ConversionFunction = conversionFunction;
    }

    public object Convert(object incomingObject)
    {
        TIncoming typedIncomingObject = (TIncoming)incomingObject;
        return ConversionFunction(typedIncomingObject);
    }
}
```

Then a utility that you can register these conversions with:

```
public static class ConversionUtility
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, IConverter>> Converters = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, IConverter>>();

    public static void RegisterConversion<TIncoming, TOutgoing>(Func<TIncoming, TOutgoing> conversionFunction)
    {
        if (!Converters.ContainsKey(typeof(TIncoming)))
        {
            Converters[typeof(TIncoming)] = new Dictionary<Type, IConverter>();
        }

        Converters[typeof(TIncoming)].Add(typeof(TOutgoing), new Converter<TIncoming, TOutgoing>(conversionFunction));
    }

    public static TOutgoing Convert<TOutgoing>(object obj)
    {
        Type incomingType = obj.GetType();

        IConverter converter = Converters[incomingType][typeof(TOutgoing)];

        return (TOutgoing)converter.Convert(obj);
    }
}
```

For usage, first you must register the conversion functions you expect to use in your application (ideally perform the registration when your application starts up to avoid threading issues):

```
ConversionUtility.RegisterConversion((float2D obj) => (Point)obj);
```

Then your conversion usage:

```
float2D V = new float2D(1, 1);
Point P = Point.Empty;
P = ConversionUtility.Convert<Point>(V); //passes
P = ConversionUtility.Convert<Point>((V as object)); //passes
```

Not sure about the performance of one over the other for your particular application usage. The first sample is a bit more flexible as it performs the check at runtime and you don't have to pre-register the conversions you expect to use. The second might be a bit more stable as you only register the conversions you expect to use and there is no reflection, just casting and dictionary lookups.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This is the only answer which address the real question.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, these two very different things. The first line:

```
P = (Point)V; // Works
```

uses the explicit conversion operator, which is **overloaded** for this combination. The second, however:

```
P = (Point)(V as object); // Specified cast is not valid.
```

this casts the reference `V` as an `object` (which we trivially know it is) - and then **separately** casts from `object` to `Point`.

Since `Point` is a `struct`, this then attempts to "unbox" that same reference as though it were a boxed `Point`. But it **is not** a boxed `Point`, so the error is correct. Conversion operators are not polymorphic, and unboxing is only allowed when the box contains a boxed copy of the appropriate type (caveat: you can unbox enums as integers, and integers as enums - as long as the underlying types match).

However, even if `Point` was a `class`, it would still fail with a similar error: reference-preserving casts also do not work if the types are incompatible.

Comment: Its worth pointing out that boxing occurs on `Point` because it is a `struct`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for this helpful information. I have a question, can I somehow ask at run-time to use an other Type instead of object. Let say I know what the real type is but I kept value and type in two different variables. Object and Type. Can I convert this object to the type (I know it is possible with T but not sure if this is possible with Type) and then use explicit casting to converting it again to, for example Point?

Comment: @SoroushFalahati there is no *nice* way to do the code in the question; there is, however, a simple but hacky way: `P = (Point)(V as dynamic);`. As for having the `Type`: that doesn't help you when it comes to conversion operators, unless you are going to write the reflection code yourself (to resolve and invoke the static conversion methods)

Comment: Would there be any major conceptual difficulty in having `ValueType` include a virtual `unbox` method whose default behavior would default to loading its contents from an `Object` with the correct type and throwing for anything else, but which could be overridden to allow other types as well, and having the `unbox` opcode invoke that method on the type in question?

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are casting it to `object` and you don't have an explicit cast for that - it won't implicitly assume you want it to be as a `float2D`.

Comment: Yes Danial, Thanks for fast response. I already know that. I was asking if this is possible to solve this problem somehow? Because as I mentioned I have a code where everything is object and I need a way to handle these conversations.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati can you use generics?

Comment: @Danial, Yes and I tested with Generics too (for methods). Yet there is an other problem. I need to keep it in a variable. So when I convert Generic Type to Object (variable type) I actually lost real data type. I think the only way is to use dynamic (as variable data type)even though I didn't wanted to use it because I like to keep code in .Net2/3.5

Comment: @SoroushFalahati I think you should add information about Framework version restriction in your question because in your case you can't use **dynamic**.

Answer (score 1):

For a truly overengineered solution combining [Chris Sinclair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20637811/3120446) using reflection with his memoized conversion methods in order to maintain performance while also not needing to call `ConversionUtility.RegisterConversion()`...

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static class ConvertUtil
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts <paramref name="source"/> to type <typeparamref name="TResult"/> 
    /// using reflection to determine the appropriate explicit or implicit cast
    /// operator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">
    /// The Type to convert <paramref name="source"/> to.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The object being converted.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// <paramref name="source"/> cast as <typeparamref name="TResult"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Detects the type of <paramref name="source"/> type at run time.  This is a
    /// minor performance hit if used frequently.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidCastException" />
    public static TResult ConvertTo<TResult>(object source) where TResult : class
    {
        if (source == null || sosurce is TResult)
        {
            return source;
        }

        Type sourceType = source?.GetType();
        return (TResult)GetConverter(sourceType, typeof(TResult))?.Invoke(source) ??
            throw new InvalidCastException($"No implicit or explicit cast from type" +
                $" {sourceType.Name} to {resultType.Name} exists.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts <paramref name="source"/> to type <typeparamref name="TResult"/> 
    /// using reflection to determine the appropriate explicit or implicit cast
    /// operator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">
    /// The type <paramref name="source"/> is being converted from.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">
    /// The Type to convert <paramref name="source"/>
    /// to.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The object being converted.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// <paramref name="source"/> cast as <typeparamref name="TResult"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Detects the type of <paramref name="source"/> type at compile time for a
    /// slight performance gain over <see cref="ConvertTo{TResult}(object)"/> if used
    /// frequently.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidCastException" />
    public static TResult ConvertTo<TSource, TResult>(TSource source) 
        where TSource : class 
        where TResult : class
    {
        if (source == null || sosurce is TResult)
        {
            return source;
        }

        Func<object, object> converter = 
            GetConverter(typeof(TSource), typeof(TResult)) ??
                throw new InvalidCastException($"No implicit or explicit cast from " +
                    $"type {sourceType.Name} to {resultType.Name} exists.");
        return (TResult)converter(source);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Lock for thread safety.  If this isn't an issue, you can remove this and all
    /// the <c>lock</c> portions of <see cref="GetConverter(Type, Type)"/>
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly object s_typeConvertersLock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// The map from source types to maps from destination types to their converting
    /// functions.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>> s_typeConverters =
        new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the first implicit or explicit defined casting operator from
    /// <paramref name="sourceType"/> to <paramref name="resultType"/>.  Returns null
    /// if no such operator is defined.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceType">The type being converted from.</param>
    /// <param name="resultType">The type being converted to.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Only searches for the cast operator once per (<paramref name="sourceType"/>,
    /// <paramref name="resultType"/>) pair.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns>
    /// The first defined casting operator from <paramref name="sourceType"/> to
    /// <paramref name="resultType"/>. Null if no operator is defined.
    /// </returns>
    private static Func<object, object> GetConverter(Type sourceType, Type resultType)
    {
        // retrieve all the operators from sourceType that we know about if we know of
        // none, add an empty map to the dictionary
        if (!s_typeConverters.TryGetValue(sourceType, 
                out Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> sourceConverters))
        {
            lock (s_typeConvertersLock)
            {
                // check again in case another thread has already added the converter
                // dictionary while waiting for the lock
                if (!s_typeConverters.TryGetValue(sourceType, out sourceConverters))
                {
                    sourceConverters = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();
                    s_typeConverters.Add(sourceType, sourceConverters);
                }
            }
        }

        // retrieve the operator from sourceType to resultType 
        // if we have not found it yet, search for it using reflection and add it to
        // the dictionary 
        // if no such cast operator exists, add still null to the dictionary so that
        // we don't need to search again
        if (!sourceConverters.TryGetValue(resultType, 
                out Func<object, object> converter))
        {
            lock (s_typeConvertersLock)
            {
                // check again in case another thread has already added the converter
                // while waiting for the lock
                if (!sourceConverters.TryGetValue(resultType, out castOperator))
                {
                    var castOperator =
                        (from method in resultType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                         where (method.Name == "op_Explicit" | 
                                method.Name == "op_Implicit") &&
                             method.ReturnType == resultType
                         let paramInfo = method.GetParameters()
                         where paramInfo.Length == 1 && 
                            paramInfo[0].ParameterType == sourceType
                         select method).FirstOrDefault();

                    converter = 
                        source => castOperator?.Invoke(null, new object[] { source });
                    sourceConverters.Add(resultType, converter);
                }
            }
        }

        return converter;
    }
}
```

The reason this method is helpful (at least to me) is that Linq's `IEnumerable<T>.Cast<TResult>()` doesn't handle implicitly or explicitly defined casting operators, only base class or interface to subclass.  I wanted to define my own overload of `Cast` (`IEnumerable<T>.Cast<T, TResult>()`) but found it troublesome because there was no way to tell the compiler that `T` can be cast to `TResult`.  Given the above, this was my solution:

```cs
namespace System.Linq
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public static class LinqExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> self)
        {
            return self.Select(item => ConvertUtil.Convert<T, TResult>(item));
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, C# doesn't allow partial inference of generic functions so I actually have to specify `T` when calling `myEnum.Cast<MyType, MyOtherType>()`.

As an aside, since I, personally, never call `ConvertUtil.ConvertTo()` in my code, I moved the memoization code into my extensions class, and put the code from `ConvertUtil.ConvertTo<TSource, TResult>()` directly in my `IEnumerable<T>.Cast<T, TResult>()` method.  The primary reason for this is so that `ConvertUtil.Convert()` isn't called once per item--only once per `IEnumerable<T>.Cast` call.  Of course, it's worth noting that usually `myIEnum.Cast<MyType1, MyType2>()` is longer than `myIEnum.Select(i => (MyType2)i)`, so there's that.